# Can't Rewrite the output of this field in views 7.x-3.3

Tags: views, theming

I don't know if I am missing something, but when I check the box for Rewrite the output of this field or anything under the style options to customize the HTML nothing happens. I check it, save it, open it again and the boxes are unchecked. Anyone know what’s going on?

**Edited for clarity**. I create a new view, with the following settings: Page, Format:Unformatted list, Show:Fields, Fields is Content: Title. In the settings for Content: Title I check to create a label.
I click under “Style settings” Customize field HTML, Customize label HTML, Customize field and label wrapper HTML or even Rewrite the output of this field, but nothing happens. If I save the checkbox goes back to unchecked

**SOLUTION** Got it. Views 7-3.3 does not work with jQuqery 1.7+. It prevents the box from expanding after clicking the checkbox

Source: http://drupal.org/node/1494860

Comment: More detail would help get your question answered. What are the settings on your view? What field are you trying to rewrite, and what are you entering in the rewrite field?

Comment: Just edited, thanks for the advice. The rewrite field never appears, I check the box and nothing happens

Comment: Do you have JavaScript enabled in your browser? Or a script blocker? It sounds like a browser problem. Or, this sounds dumb but I have done dumber things, make sure you've scrolled down enough to see if anything outside the field of view of that tiny text window changed.

Comment: got it, see above. Cheers

Comment: If you found the solution, you can answer your own question and select it, so the question can be marked as answered, for the benefit of anyone in the future who searches this topic.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

SOLUTION Got it. Views 7-3.3 does not work with jQuqery 1.7+. It prevents the box from expanding after clicking the checkbox

Source: http://drupal.org/node/1494860

Comment: ok. So, what needs to be done?

Answer (score 1):

The same problem happens when you use jQuery 1.10 or 1.9 with Drupal 7.31. Trying to edit a field in a View and checking boxes does not expand the relevant form elements.

One solution is to use the [jQuery Update](https://www.drupal.org/project/jquery_update) module that upgrades the version of jQuery in Drupal core to a newer version of jQuery.

Download the module, enable it and go to the page **/admin/config/development/jquery_update**. The "Default jQuery Version" dropdown menu allows you to select the version of jQuery that you want to use.

I selected the 1.8 jQuery version and now I have no problem editing the View fields.